# How would I check for mouse click on Python 3.8?

Tags: python, kivy

## How do I check for LMB in Python?

I want to check for when the left mouse button (left click) is clicked to make a drawing system through Kivy. I can’t find it anywhere or figure out how to do it.

```py
if draw_mode_free == True:
    if playerClicking == True:
        with self.canvas:
   # draw a line using the default color
   Line(points=(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3))

   # lets draw a semi-transparent red square
   Color(0, 0, 0, 1, mode='rgba')
   Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard Kivy `on_touch_down`, `on_touch_move` and `on_touch_up` methods to receive and make use of incoming touch events (which includes mouse clicks).

The touch objects you receive include data about what button is pressed, accessible via `touch.profile['button']` (and possibly directly via `touch.button`, not sure).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a pice of code which can give the mouse click
Try this on your project it may help you

```py
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
def on_click(x,y, button,pressed):
     if pressed:
         print("mouse click")
```